# 指定した上限値の値分、各配列に要素を追加する

Tags: python, python3

slice_list_dataとdict_dataのデータがあります。

slice_list_data→スライス値が含まれた空配列のリスト
dict_data→各keyに配列の要素が含まれた辞書

こちらのリストに辞書内のデータを格納したいのですが、思った通りの格納が出来ない状態です。
もし、お分かりの方がいましたら、教えて頂けますと幸いです。

```
# 自身の出力結果
[[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[1, 2]
[3]
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7]
[1]
[1, 2, 3]]

# 期待する出力結果
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2], 
 [3], 
 [1, 2], 
 [3, 4, 5], 
 [1, 2], 
 [3, 4, 5, 6], 
 [7], 
 [1], 
 [1, 2],  
 [3]]
```

現在は、リストの5番目までは期待する結果になるのですが、
それ以降は思いつかない状態です。

よろしくお願い致します。

現状試したコードを下記に記載します。

```
slice_list_data = [[[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
             [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
             [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
             [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
             [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
             [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]]]

dict_data = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             2: [1, 2, 3],
             3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
             5: [1],
             6: [1, 2, 3]}


# ここで各keyに格納されている要素を、指定した値まで各配列に格納
temp_list = []
for list_num, i in enumerate(list_data):
    for list_idx, j in enumerate(i):
        temp_list.append([])
        temp_list[list_num].append(dict_data[list_num+1][j[1]:j[2]])
        
value_only_list = [ j for i in temp_list for j in i if j != [] ]

# 指定した値をvalue_only_listの要素数分追加する
# 例: [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2,・・・・, 4, 2, 4, 2]
upper_limit_list = []

count = 0
while True:
    for i in num_list:
        upper_limit_list.append(i)
        
    count += len(num_list)
    
    if count > len(value_only_list*n_val):
        break
        
# ここでは、指定した値分配列に格納されてるか確認、もし超えていた場合、再度詰め直し
for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(upper_limit_list, value_only_list)):
    if len(y) > x:
        value_only_list[idx] = y[:x]
        value_only_list.insert(idx+1, y[x:])
        
        
# 出力結果確認
for x in value_only_list:
    print(x)
    
    
# 期待する出力結果
result = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2], 
 [3], 
 [1, 2], 
 [3, 4, 5], 
 [1, 2], 
 [3, 4, 5, 6], 
 [7], 
 [1], 
 [1, 2],  
 [3]]


print('期待する出力結果', result)
```

Comment: 前半で`value_only_list`生成し, 後半で `[4,2]*n` のサイズ毎にさらに分割してるようで合成してる処理は無さそう。なので `[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9],` のように分割され, 「期待する出力結果」のように `[3, 4, 5]` (5が途中に) が現れることはありえないのでは？

Comment: もしも`[3, 4]` と `[5]` もしくは `[5,6]` を合成する必要があるなら, どんなルールで行うかを質問に記してないとムリでしょう

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。こちら、自己解決致しました。

Comment: 自己回答が可能であれば 自己回答して, 解決済みにするとよいかも

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決

```
# そもそものデータ構成変更
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3]
num_list = [4, 2, 4, 2]

num_list2 = []

count = 0
while True:
    for i in num_list:
        num_list2.append(i)
        
    count += len(num_list)
        
    if count >= len(data):
        
        break
        
        
data[0] = 0

tmp_list = [[]]

data_idx = 0
list_idx = 0

# 下記処理でデータの中身一つずつ確認して空リストに格納する
while data_idx < len(data):
    target_val = data[data_idx]
    storage_list = num_list2[list_idx]

    if target_val == 1 or len(tmp_list[list_idx]) == storage_list:
        list_idx += 1
        tmp_list.append([])

    tmp_list[list_idx].append(target_val)

    data_idx += 1
        
        
tmp_list
```

Answer (score 0):

これは質問に対する回答ではなく
質問に記載されているコードが動かなかったための, 変更です

もとの`upper_limit_list` の代わりに `iter(cycle())` を使用
(質問を改訂する場合などに, もしも参考になるような部分があればどうぞ)

```py
from itertools import cycle
import pprint

slice_list_data = [
    [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
    [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
    [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
    [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
    [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]],
    [[[], 0, 4], [[], 4, 6], [[], 6, 10], [[], 10, 12]]]

dict_data = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             2: [1, 2, 3],
             3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
             5: [1],
             6: [1, 2, 3]}

# dict_data の内容から, slice_list_data による抜き出し
value_only_list = []
for p, row in enumerate(slice_list_data):
    for col in row:
        v = dict_data[p +1][col[1]: col[2]]
        if v: value_only_list.append(v)

# 指定の長さより長い項目は, さらに分割
it = iter(cycle((4,2)))
res = []
for v in value_only_list:
    sz = next(it)
    #print(v, sz)
    while len(v) > sz:
        res.append(v[:sz])
        v = v[sz:]
        sz = next(it)

    if v: res.append(v)

# 中間結果, 最終結果
pprint.pprint(value_only_list)
pprint.pprint(res)
```

---

【問題点】(コメントから転載)
前半で`value_only_list`生成し, 後半で `[4,2]*n` のサイズ毎にさらに分割してるようで, 合成してる処理は無さそう。
なので `[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9],` のように分割され, 「期待する出力結果」のように `[3, 4, 5]` (5が途中に) が現れることは無いのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうござます。そもそものデータ構成が間違っているのを気付き、再度質問に投稿しました。ただ、コメントを頂いたソースは他のところで使える場面がなりそうなので、参考にさせて頂きます